# Spring Integration + @Aysnc - Gateway vs ServiceActivator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a remote service that I'm calling to load pricing data for a product, when a specific event occurs. Once loaded, the product pricing is then broadcast for another consumer to process elsewhere.

The calling code doesn't care about the response - it's fire-and-forget, responding to an application event, and triggering a new workflow.

In order to keep the calling code as quick as possible, I'd like to use @Async here, but I'm having mixed results.

The basic flow is:

```
CallingCode -> ProductPricingGateway -> Aggregator -> BatchedFetchPricingTask
```

Here's the Async setup:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1" />
<task:executor id="executor" keep-alive="30" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="500" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

The other two components used are a `@Gateway`, which the intiating code calls, and a down-stream `@ServiceActivator`, that sits behind an aggregator.  (Calls are batched into small groups).

```
public interface ProductPricingGateway {    
    @Gateway(requestChannel="product.pricing.outbound.requests")
    public void broadcastPricing(ProductIdentifer productIdentifier);
}

// ...elsewhere...
@Component
public class BatchedFetchPricingTask {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="product.pricing.outbound.requests.batch")
    public void fetchPricing(List<ProductIdentifer> identifiers)
    {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

And the other relevant intergation config:

```
<int:gateway service-interface="ProductPricingGateway"
    default-request-channel="product.pricing.outbound.requests" />

<int:channel id="product.pricing.outbound.requests" />
<int:channel id="product.pricing.outbound.requests.batch" />
```

I find that if I declare `@Async` on the `@ServiceActivator` method, it works fine.
However, if I declare it on the `@Gateway` method (which seems like a more appropriate place), the aggregator is never invoked.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to see how `@Async` would work anywhere here, because the starting point is when your code calls the `ProductPricingGateway.broadcastPricing()` method.

With `@Async` on the gw, what would the scheduler send?

Similarly, with `@Async` on the service, what would the scheduler pass in in `identifiers`?

The correct way to go async as soon as possible would be to make `product.pricing.outbound.requests` an `ExecutorChannel`...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel

...where the calling thread hands off the message to a task executor.